# dygraphs Mismatch between number of labels and number of columns in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dygraphs

Can't get the dygraphs to work.

I have an array populated from PHP that looks like:

```
data = [
{
    "DATA": "2016-01-22",
    "TOTAL": [
        "7",
        "4",
        "20",
        "0"
    ]
},
{
    "DATA": "2016-01-25",
    "TOTAL": [
        "3",
        "2",
        "10",
        "0"
    ]
},
{
    "DATA": "2016-01-26",
    "TOTAL": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "4",
        "0"
    ]
},
{
    "DATA": "2016-01-27",
    "TOTAL": [
        "2",
        "1",
        "2",
        "0"
    ]
},
{
    "DATA": "2016-02-02",
    "TOTAL": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "0"
    ]
},
{
    "DATA": "2016-02-10",
    "TOTAL": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "3",
        "0"
    ]
}
]
```

I then build the data for the graph as:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    var adata = item.DATA;
    var atotal = item.TOTAL;

    graphstr1 += '[new Date("' + adata + '"),' + atotal + '],';
});
graphstr1 = graphstr1.slice(0, -1);
console.log(graphstr1);
```

Looking at the console, the data is in the required format, but I always get the error in que question title

Dygraph code:

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"), [
        graphstr1,
        /*[new Date("2016-01-22"), 7, 4, 20, 0],
        [new Date("2016-01-25"), 3, 2, 10, 0],
        [new Date("2016-01-26"), 1, 1, 4, 0],
        [new Date("2016-01-27"), 2, 1, 2, 0],
        [new Date("2016-02-02"), 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [new Date("2016-02-10"), 1, 1, 3, 0]*/

    ], {
        labels: ["x", "Registados", "Grávidas", "Com Filhos", "Sem Filhos"]
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an array directly without a self made stringifyed version?

```js
var data = [{ DATA: "2016-01-22", TOTAL: ["7", "4", "20", "0"] }, { DATA: "2016-01-25", TOTAL: ["3", "2", "10", "0"] }, { DATA: "2016-01-26", TOTAL: ["1", "1", "4", "0"] }, { DATA: "2016-01-27", TOTAL: ["2", "1", "2", "0"] }, { DATA: "2016-02-02", TOTAL: ["1", "1", "1", "0"] }, { DATA: "2016-02-10", TOTAL: ["1", "1", "3", "0"] }],
    converted = data.map(function (a) {
        return [new Date(a.DATA)].concat(a.TOTAL.map(Number));
    }),
    g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
        converted, 
        { labels: ["x", "Registados", "Grávidas", "Com Filhos", "Sem Filhos"] });
```

```html
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried your code, but still get error: Mismatch between number of labels (x,Registados,Grávidas,Com Filhos,Sem Filhos) and number of columns in array

Comment: Darn! It does in deed! :) I see my problem was using: g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"), [ graphstr1]... instead of g = new Dygraph( document.getElementById("graphdiv"), graphstr1